# Verticalize XML using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am trying to implement an at first looking simple transformation but whatever I have tried has been failed.
The XML is generated from a fixed length record and have the below format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<record>
    <no_of_records>30</no_of_records>   
    <cust_lastname_1>Smith</cust_lastname_1>
    <cust_name_1>John</cust_name_1>
    <cust_id_1>X45</cust_id_1>
    <cust_lastname_2>George</cust_lastname_2>
    <cust_name_2>Michael</cust_name_2>
    <cust_id_2>X76</cust_id_2>
    <cust_lastname_3>Ria</cust_lastname_3>
    <cust_name_3>Chris</cust_name_3>
    <cust_id_3>C87</cust_id_3>
    ...
</record>
```

The no_of_records indicates how many _X suffixed elements contains each record and because of its fix length origin has a defined maximum.
I want to transform it to a “verticalized” form resempling the below.

```
<record>
    <customer num="1">
        <lastname>Smith</lastname>
        <name>John</name>
        <id>X45</id>
    </customer>
    <customer num="2">
        <lastname>George</lastname>
        <name>Michael</name>
        <id>X76</id>
    </customer> 
    <customer num="3">
        <lastname>Ria</lastname>
        <name>Chris</name>
        <id>C87</id>
        ...
    </customer>     
</record>
```

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Your input XML is malformed.  It has start tags where you appear to want end tags, and even then, not all of the closing tags presented match the corresponding open tags.

Comment: Since you say that this XML is generated from a fixed-length record, is there any chance of generating the XML form you want directly from that record?  Alternatively, could the initial XML generation be made to produce a form that could be transformed more easily into your desired output, as well as into the form that you present in the question as your input?

Comment: The task you call "verticalization" is often called "positional grouping" - you might like to use that as a search term.

Comment: michael.hor257k, Yes XSLT 2.0 is available.
JohnBollinger, fixed the xml , unfortunately the source xml format can't be changed.
MichaelKay, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, you want something like

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'cust_lastname']">
  <customer num="{position()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
  </customer>
</xsl:for-each-group>

....

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'cust')]">
  <xsl:element name="{replace(local-name(), 'cust_(.*?)_[0-9]+', '$1')}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @Michael Kay works fine. Thank you !

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<record>
    <no_of_records>3</no_of_records>   
    <cust_lastname_1>Smith</cust_lastname_1>
    <cust_name_1>John</cust_name_1>
    <cust_id_1>X45</cust_id_1>
    <cust_lastname_2>George</cust_lastname_2>
    <cust_name_2>Michael</cust_name_2>
    <cust_id_2>X76</cust_id_2>
    <cust_lastname_3>Ria</cust_lastname_3>
    <cust_name_3>Chris</cust_name_3>
    <cust_id_3>C87</cust_id_3>
</record>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="record">
    <records>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'cust_')]"
        group-starting-with="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'cust_lastname')]">
        <customer num="{position()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </customer>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </records>
  </xsl:template>    
  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'cust')]">
      <xsl:element name="{replace(local-name(), 'cust_(.*?)_[0-9]+', '$1')}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records>
   <customer num="1">
      <lastname>Smith</lastname>
      <name>John</name>
      <id>X45</id>
   </customer>
   <customer num="2">
      <lastname>George</lastname>
      <name>Michael</name>
      <id>X76</id>
   </customer>
   <customer num="3">
      <lastname>Ria</lastname>
      <name>Chris</name>
      <id>C87</id>
   </customer>
</records>
```